# Does gevent has a basic http handler?

Tags: python, http, gevent, greenlets

I am trying to build a basic web server using gevent.server, and curious to know is there any baseHTTPHandlers, I can use.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, gevent comes with two HTTP server implementations you can use:

- gevent.wsgi - fast, libevent-based implementation, but providing limited features.
- gevent.pywsgi - slower, pure gevent implementation, but providing more features (streaming, pipelining, SSL).

Here is a simple example (extracted from gevent documentation):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""WSGI server example"""
from __future__ import print_function
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

def application(env, start_response):
    if env['PATH_INFO'] == '/':
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        return [b"<b>hello world</b>"]
    else:
        start_response('404 Not Found', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        return [b'<h1>Not Found</h1>']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Serving on 8088...')
    WSGIServer(('', 8088), application).serve_forever()
```

For more information, see http://www.gevent.org/servers.html

See also http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/08/building-web-applications-with-gevents.html